# Why does my video feed hang after a while (Not Responding) on Python open cv?

Tags: python, qr-code, barcode, opencv

I'm currently trying to write a programme that can open a live video feed (webcam) and identify QR or Barcodes live as they appear under the camera but the video feed always hangs after a while. I am running this on python and I have imported the following libraries:

- qrcode
- csv
- cv2
- numpy
- from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

Here is the function that I call in the console:

```
def open_camera():
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:MCCUED@192.168.1.112/H264?ch=1&subtype=0')

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    for barcode in decode(img):
        idString = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
        pts = np.array([barcode.polygon], np.int32)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        
        pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        cv2.polylines(img, [pts], True, (100, 100, 255), 5)
        pts2 = barcode.rect
        draw_text(img, "ID:" + idString, font_scale=2, pos=(pts2[0], pts2[1] - 44), text_color_bg=(0, 0, 0))

    cv2.imshow('Result', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output: The video feed appears and runs for a while and can detect some QR/Barcodes BUT it hangs after like 10 seconds and shows not responding. I also get this error: [image]

---

Helper function'draw_text' just places a background box under my text for clearer text output:

```
def draw_text(img, text,
          font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
          pos=(0, 0),
          font_scale=3,
          font_thickness=2,
          text_color=(0, 255, 0),
          text_color_bg=(0, 0, 0)
          ):
x, y = pos
text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, font_scale, font_thickness)
text_w, text_h = text_size
cv2.rectangle(img, pos, (x + text_w, y + text_h), text_color_bg, -1)
cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y + text_h + font_scale - 1), font, font_scale, text_color, font_thickness)

return text_size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success, img = cap.read()
```

you absolutely must check:

```
if not success:
    break
```

it means the video has ended or the stream was interrupted.

AND you must check (assert) `cap.isOpened()` once before even entering the loop

so many people think these steps are optional. they are not. they are essential. do not follow tutorials that get this wrong.